# Dock and Anchor in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am coming from a WinForms background and am starting to learn WPF.  I've gone through a set of tutorials at Pluralsight, but am having a little difficulty with handling resizing.

When resizing, my textboxes don't seem to be "anchoring" in the way I would want.  I'm including the xaml below with notes in it as to the behavior I am looking for.  Any feedback regarding best practices would be very much appreciated.  The code just "feels" a little awkward to me, but I'm not sure if that is because it's just new to me, or if there are easier/better ways of doing what I am attempting.

To get an idea of what things look like without needing to load the XAML below - here are before and after resizing the form screenshots.
[Before Resize http://dboasis.com/screenshots/beforeresize.jpg](http://dboasis.com/screenshots/beforeresize.jpg)
[After Resize http://dboasis.com/screenshots/afterresize.jpg](http://dboasis.com/screenshots/afterresize.jpg)

I'm hoping for suggestions both how to handle the resize issues, as well as best practices after seeing how I've attempted to do it in the XAML.

Also - the xaml does implement DevExpress controls - if anyone wants me to redo the form and not use 3rd party controls so they more easily make suggestions, I am happy to do so.

```
<dx:DXWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
    xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid" xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors" x:Class="DXTemplateSandbox.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="437" Width="641">
<Grid>
    <dx:DXTabControl x:Name="tabcntMainTab">
        <dx:DXTabItem x:Name="tabUserList" Header="User List">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition x:Name="SelectLabel" Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition x:Name="OpenDataFile" Height="34" />
                    <RowDefinition x:Name="DataGridLayoutRow" Height="185*" />
                    <RowDefinition x:Name="AppPrefsInfo" Height="110" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0">
                    <!-- 
                    The DataFileLocation not resizing the width.  How do I instead lock the vertical size, but allow width to
                    resize with form?
                    -->
                    <TextBox Name="DataFileLocation" Width="419" Margin="0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

                    <!--
                    How do I get the SelectData button stay immediately to the right of the DatFileLocation textbox when resizing?
                    -->
                    <Button Name="SelectData" Content="..." Width="40" Margin="5" Click="SelectData_Click"/>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <!-- I would like the "Go" button to stay anchored to the right when resizing. -->
                        <Button x:Name="GoButton" 
                                Content="Go" 
                                Width="66" 
                                DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Margin="50,5,5,5" 
                                Click="GoButton_Click" />
                    </DockPanel>

                </StackPanel>

                <!--
                -->
                <dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" >
                    <dxg:GridControl.View>
                        <dxg:TableView ShowGroupPanel="False"/>
                    </dxg:GridControl.View>
                </dxg:GridControl>

                <Label Content="Select Data File" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="91"/>

                <!-- 
                Is using a grid inside a parent grid cell the best way of doing this?  I'm using stackpanels in each of the rows in the
                child grid.  Is there a better way of doing this?  
                -->
                <Grid x:Name="AppPrefsGrid" Grid.Row="3" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!--
                    Ideally I would like the text boxes to grow and shrink at the same rate as form is resized, and leave the labels the same width.  I don't know
                    if this is practical however.
                    -->
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Registration Name:" Width="112" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox Name="RegNameTextBox" Width="175" Margin="5" IsEnabled="False"/>
                        <Label Content="Install Date:" Width="84" Margin="10,5,5,5"/>
                        <TextBox Name="InstallDateTextBox" Width="175" Margin="5" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Registration Number:" Width="112" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox Name="RegNumberTextBox" Width="175" Margin="5" IsEnabled="False"/>
                        <Label Content="Data File Version:" Width="84" Margin="10,5,5,5"/>
                        <TextBox Name="DataVersionTextBox" Width="175" Margin="5" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Edition Code:" Width="112" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox Name="EditionCodeTextBox" Width="175" Margin="5" IsEnabled="False"/>
                        <Label Content="User Count:" Width="84" Margin="10,5,5,5"/>
                        <TextBox Name="UserCountTextBox" Width="175" Margin="5" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    </StackPanel>


                </Grid>

            </Grid>

        </dx:DXTabItem>
        <dx:DXTabItem x:Name="tabKeyGen" Header="Key Generator"/>
    </dx:DXTabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If you're new to WPF from WinForms, I would highly recommend checking out this article: [WPF Layouts - A Visual Quick Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start). It should help you understand WPF's layout system a little better :) But it sounds like you want to host your controls in a `Grid` with the `Label` columns width set to a static number, and the content columns width set to a `*` size so it stretches to fill all remaining space

Comment: Tip: Don't use the Visual Studio designer, it produces fixed-size, fixed-position content that does not work well when resizing the Window, or in different resolutions.

Comment: HighCore: I am doing things in the xaml for the most part, but did use a little bit of drag/drop to get controls onto the form.  Since I'm on a learning curve here, using the VS designer as a starting point is helpful, to get an idea of where in the xaml to put things, and syntax for properties.  Are there any specific "gotchas" that I should be watching out for if using the designer in Visual Studio?

Comment: Rachel, thanks for the link - however I didn't really see anything there that wasn't in the pluralsight training I've already done.  I edited the post and included some screenshots of what the form looks like before and after resizing to make it easier to get an idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have multiple problems here that appear to be because you are not using the correct layout panel for your controls.

By default, the size of a control is based on the behavior of the parent.

For example, items placed inside a `Grid` will stretch to fill all available space given to them inside the Grid Cell. If the Grid Row/Column definition has a Height/Width set to `Auto` it means it will draw the control at whatever size the control wants. If it's set to a fixed size such as `100`, then it will draw the control at that size. If it's set to a `*` size, it will draw the control using a percentage of the remaining space.

This behavior can be overridden by properties on the control itself, such as `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment`, or setting properties such as the `Height`, `Width`, and `Margin`.

So, to address some of your specific problems, start by removing those stack panels hosting your label/textbox combinations and replace them with a proper 3x4 `Grid`. Put your labels in columns 0 and 2 and give that `ColumnDefinition` a fixed size. Put your TextBoxes in columns 1 and 3, and leave them as a `*` size. Remember, a `*` size is a percentage, so 2* in one column and 3* in another column will mean there are `5*` available total, and column 1 will take up 2/5 of the space while column2 will take up 3/5th of the space.

To get your `DataFileLocation` to resize as the form resizes, simply remove the `Width` property and let it size to whatever size the grid cell is.

To get the `SelectData` button to stay docked to the right of the `SelectData` textbox, place both in a `DockPanel`. Dock the Button to the Right side, and allow the TextBox to fill all remaining space. You will have to set the TabIndex if you want the tab key to cycle through them as expected.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" ... />
    <TextBox ... />
</DockPanel>
```

Start with that, and see how it looks. Your RowDefinition for your parent grid looks correct (other than the fact your 3rd row height should be `"*"` and not `"184*"`), and it should mean your DevExpress control should stretch/shrink to fill all remaining vertical space.